# Does the reaction of 2‐hydroxy‐6‐methyl‐5‐nitrocyclohepta‐2,4,6‐trien‐1‐one with NaOH involve ring contraction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, pericyclic

> What is the product and mechanism when 2‐hydroxy‐6‐methyl‐5‐nitrocyclohepta‐2,4,6‐trien‐1‐one is reacted with
>   $\ce{NaOH}$?
>
> [image: 2‐hydroxy‐6‐methyl‐5‐nitrocyclohepta‐2,4,6‐trien‐1‐one + NaOH]

The only reagent used is $\ce{NaOH}$ so I suppose it abstracts the acidic hydrogen from the $\ce{-OH}$ group. A nucleophilic attack at the carbonyl carbon is also possible, as it could form a tropylium like cation. But I am not sure as to how a ring contraction occurs. The final answer given is 3-methyl-4-nitrobenzoic acid. How does the formation of an acid group and the ring contraction take place?

Comment: It may be worthwhile drawing the dicarbonyl tautomer and thinking of a possible C-H deprotonation, and also considering the mechanism of the Favorskii rearrangement.

Comment: Electrocyclization would get you to the Favorskii intermediate. Alternatively,  the @Waylander diketone may undergo a benzylic acid rearrangement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drawing on the suggestion of @user55119 I propose the mechanism shown below.

Whether the first intermediate bicyclic [4.1.0] heptanone arises from an intramolecular electrocyclic process or an intramolecular aldol is unclear but either seems possible. Once the highly strained bicyclic [4.1.0] heptanone intermediate is formed, the reaction proceeds with OH- attack on the carbonyl in a process analogous to a Favorskii [mechanism here](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/favorsky-reaction.shtm), with the second intermediate anion stabilised by the nitro group which also directs the direction of ring opening. Finally loss of OH- in a manner similar to base-catalysed aldol and driven by re-aromatisation gives the observed product. 
[image]

Comment: I no longer have Scifinder access to see if this is a literature example. If anyone who does would care to post the reference, please do.